# Windows tool to write socket output to file

Tags: c#, networking

Does anyone know of a Windows tool that will write the output from a network socket to a file?

Open Source (preferably C#) would be preferred, but not essential.

I know it would probably be pretty simple to write one, but I am guessing that an existing tool would probably have features that I haven't even realised I want yet.

Comment: Voted for migration because you're looking for a ready-to-use-tool, and not for the way how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Netcat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) should do what you want on Windows. (Not C#, admittedly.)